# DnsClient Incompatible change

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

I've added some DNS activities (mostly TXT lookups) to my micro-service. After adding these I'm unable to package as per normal issuing `./mvnw package -DskipTests --activate-profiles native --also-make`

After adding the lookup routines the following is returned

```
Error: Incompatible change of initialization policy for com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient: trying to change RUN_TIME from command line with 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient' to RERUN Contains Random references, therefore can't be included in the image heap.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Incompatible change of initialization policy for com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient: trying to change RUN_TIME from command line with 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient' to RERUN Contains Random references, therefore can't be included in the image heap.
```

the relevant part (I believe) of my applications.properties file is currently

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=\
  -H:+PrintClassInitialization,\
  --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime,\
  --trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom,\
  --initialize-at-run-time=java.security.SecureRandom\\,sun.security.jca.JCAUtil\\,com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient
```

Before adding the DNS related methods I did not have `quarkus.native.additional-build-args` in my application.properties file. After adding the DNS routines there were errors related to `java.security.SecureRandom` about which there were some hints at [Quarkus - TIPS FOR WRITING NATIVE APPLICATIONS](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips) and so I added

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=\
  -H:+PrintClassInitialization,\
  --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime,\
  --initialize-at-run-time=java.security.SecureRandom
```

this got me a bit further but still returned

```
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 java.security.SecureRandom the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from command line with 'java.security.SecureRandom'). To see why java.security.SecureRandom got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom
To see how the classes got initialized, use --trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 java.security.SecureRandom the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from command line with 'java.security.SecureRandom'). To see why java.security.SecureRandom got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom
```

so modified application.properties as with `--trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom` as directed in the error message to get the new error message

```
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 java.security.SecureRandom the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from command line with 'java.security.SecureRandom'). com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
        at java.security.SecureRandom.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:158)
        at sun.security.jca.JCAUtil$CachedSecureRandomHolder.<clinit>(JCAUtil.java:58)
        at sun.security.jca.JCAUtil.getSecureRandom(JCAUtil.java:70)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<clinit>(DnsClient.java:86)


com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 java.security.SecureRandom the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from command line with 'java.security.SecureRandom'). com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
        at java.security.SecureRandom.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:158)
        at sun.security.jca.JCAUtil$CachedSecureRandomHolder.<clinit>(JCAUtil.java:58)
        at sun.security.jca.JCAUtil.getSecureRandom(JCAUtil.java:70)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<clinit>(DnsClient.java:86)
```

this is how I reached my current application.properties entry of `quarkus.native.additional-build-args` of

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=\
  -H:+PrintClassInitialization,\
  --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime,\
  --trace-class-initialization=java.security.SecureRandom,\
  --initialize-at-run-time=java.security.SecureRandom\\,sun.security.jca.JCAUtil\\,com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient
```

I do have a local copy of graalvm with native installed that I have been using but have also tried with `quarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:22.3-java17` and `quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17` where I've set `quarkus.native.container-build=true`

I'm not sure what I can try next. Or, if that the use of the `com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient` means that a native package is out of the question. Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the answer you are looking for, but I would not use JNDI to read a TXT record. You can use the Vert.x DNS client to achieve the same thing and that would work in native OOTB.

So something like:

```
@Inject Vertx vertx;

// ...
var dns = vertx.createDnsClient(...);
```

See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_dns_client.